# выборка из файла по совпадению в сроке файла передаваемой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

хочу произвести выбор строки, в которой есть совпадение. Вот так работает

```
def get_return(time_input):
    with open('nginx.log','r') as file:
        for str1 in file:
            get_time = str1[str1.find(':')-2 : str1.find(':')+6]
            while (time_input == get_time):
                print ('show get_time : ' + get_time)
                return str1

vr = get_return('07:01:45')
print (vr)
```

а вот так нет.

```
def return_time():
    with open('nginx-time.log','r') as file:
        for str1 in file:
            time = str1
            print ('show time : ' + time)
            
            check = get_return(time)          
            print('show check : ' + str(check))
```

Возвращает None.
Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в первом случае есть return, а во втором нет. А когда нет return, то функция в любом случае возвращает None.

Comment: Вот что выводится после выполнения: 
show time : 11:51:25

show check : None
None 
Почему при выполнении get_return(time) возвращает именно None? Ведь если выполнить get_return('07:01:45'), то вернёт значение

Comment: Вот содержание файла "nginx-time.log" 11:51:25
11:51:55
11:51:14
11:51:13
11:51:17
11:51:20
11:51:21

Comment: Я разобрался в чём было дело: нужно было удалить символ возврата каретки "\n" в конце строки. Теперь другой вопрос: как посчитать количество совпадений в строках? Точнее количество строк, которые совпадают с принимаемым значением?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает как надо.

```
def get_return(time_input):
    count = 0 # число совпадений
    with open('nginx.log','r') as file:
        for str1 in file:   # по каждой строке пробегаем
            get_time = str1[str1.find(':')-2 : str1.find(':')+6]
            
            #while (time_input == get_time):
            if (time_input == get_time):
                #print ('show get_time : ' + get_time)
                count+=1            
    return count

def return_time():
    with open('nginx-time.log','r') as file:
        for str1 in file:
            time = str1.rstrip('\n')
            #print ('show time : ' + time)
            
            check = get_return(time)          
            #print('show check : ' + str(check))
        return check
```